# How to get the ROWGUIDCOL in SQL Server 2000 table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, uniqueidentifier

How can i determine the name of the `ROWGUIDCOL` column in an SQL Server 2000 table?

i tried looking through [`syscolumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398.aspx), e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Currencies')
```

But there is nothing there, or on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398.aspx) that looks like `rowguidcol`.

---

### Easy in SQL Server 2005

In SQL Server 2005 you just have to query `sys.columns`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Currencies')
AND is_rowguidcol = 1
```

Easy peasey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [COLUMNPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226011%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(id, name, 'IsRowGuidCol'), * FROM syscolumns ... ;
```

In the format of the original question:

```
SELECT *
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Currencies')
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(id, name, 'IsRowGuidCol') = 1;
```

Comment: 'Currencies' is name of table;

Comment: @zloctb yes, is that a question?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, if you don't know the rowguid column and you want to select it (but don't need to know its name for any other reason than to select it) you can do this:

```
SELECT $rowguid FROM YourTable;
```

If the table doesn't have a rowguid column:

- In SQL 2000 you will get a column with name `rowguid` full of the value `0.00`.
- In SQL 2005 and up you will get an error, `Invalid column name '$rowguid'`.

For completeness note that in SQL 2005 and up you can also use `$identity` to get a table's identity column without knowing its name. In SQL 2000 you get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.`

Comment: `SELECT $rowguid FROM MyTable` returns all `0.00` on a table without a `ROWGUIDCOL`.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian, I was checking SQL 2008. In SQL 2000 it must be different!